# AWS Glue, PySpark || Error in reading from RDS as DynamicFrame

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, pyspark, aws-glue

I am creating a dynamic frame from an RDS table using the below code. It works well for other tables but giving a weird error for one of the tables - "java.sql.SQLException: DAY_OF_MONTH". The error trace is also below. Kindly help.

```
dyf = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_options(connection_type = "mysql",
                                                connection_options = {"url": "jdbc:mysql://endpoint:port/database", 
                                                                      "dbtable": "table_name",
                                                                      "user": userDestination,
                                                                      "password": passwordDestination,
                                                                      "customJdbcDriverClassName": jarDriver,
                                                                      "customJdbcDriverS3Path": jarPath},
                                                additional_options = {"jobBookmarkKeys": ["PK_ID"],
                                                                      "jobBookmarksKeysSortOrder": "asc"},
                                                transformation_ctx = "dyf")
```

Error trace

> An error was encountered: An error occurred while calling o1031.count.
>   : org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure:
>   Task 0 in stage 194.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task
>   0.3 in stage 194.0 (, executor 28): java.sql.SQLException: DAY_OF_MONTH   at
>   com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:129)
>     at
>   com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97)
>     at
>   com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:89)
>     at
>   com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:63)
>     at
>   com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:73)
>     at
>   com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:85)
>     at
>   com.mysql.cj.jdbc.result.ResultSetImpl.getDate(ResultSetImpl.java:755)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$jdbc$JdbcUtils$$makeGetter$2.apply(JdbcUtils.scala:389)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$jdbc$JdbcUtils$$makeGetter$2.apply(JdbcUtils.scala:387)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$$anon$1.getNext(JdbcUtils.scala:356)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$$anon$1.getNext(JdbcUtils.scala:338)
>     at org.apache.spark.util.NextIterator.hasNext(NextIterator.scala:73)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.util.CompletionIterator.hasNext(CompletionIterator.scala:31)
>     at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.UnsafeExternalRowSorter.sort(UnsafeExternalRowSorter.java:216)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.exchange.ShuffleExchangeExec$$anonfun$2.apply(ShuffleExchangeExec.scala:295)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.exchange.ShuffleExchangeExec$$anonfun$2.apply(ShuffleExchangeExec.scala:266)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$24.apply(RDD.scala:836)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$24.apply(RDD.scala:836)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
>     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
>     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
>     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
>     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:99)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:55)
>     at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:121)  at
>   org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:408)
>     at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:414)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by:
>   com.mysql.cj.exceptions.WrongArgumentException: DAY_OF_MONTH  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>     at
>   com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:61)
>     at
>   com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:105)
>     at
>   com.mysql.cj.result.SqlDateValueFactory.localCreateFromDate(SqlDateValueFactory.java:85)
>     at
>   com.mysql.cj.result.SqlDateValueFactory.localCreateFromDate(SqlDateValueFactory.java:50)
>     at
>   com.mysql.cj.result.AbstractDateTimeValueFactory.createFromDate(AbstractDateTimeValueFactory.java:67)
>     at
>   com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.MysqlBinaryValueDecoder.decodeDate(MysqlBinaryValueDecoder.java:129)
>     at
>   com.mysql.cj.protocol.result.AbstractResultsetRow.decodeAndCreateReturnValue(AbstractResultsetRow.java:90)
>     at
>   com.mysql.cj.protocol.result.AbstractResultsetRow.getValueFromBytes(AbstractResultsetRow.java:241)
>     at
>   com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.result.ByteArrayRow.getValue(ByteArrayRow.java:91)
>     ... 29 more Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   DAY_OF_MONTH  at
>   java.util.GregorianCalendar.computeTime(GregorianCalendar.java:2648)
>     at java.util.Calendar.updateTime(Calendar.java:3393)    at
>   java.util.Calendar.getTimeInMillis(Calendar.java:1782)    at
>   com.mysql.cj.result.SqlDateValueFactory.localCreateFromDate(SqlDateValueFactory.java:82)
>     ... 35 more
>
> Driver stacktrace:    at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1889)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1877)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1876)
>     at
>   scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
>     at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1876)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:926)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:926)
>     at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)   at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:926)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2110)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2059)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2048)
>     at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:737)
>     at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2061)    at
>   org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2082)     at
>   org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2101)     at
>   org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2126)     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.count(RDD.scala:1168)    at
>   com.amazonaws.services.glue.DynamicFrame.count(DynamicFrame.scala:1145)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)  at
>   py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)    at
>   py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)     at
>   py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
>     at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)   at
>   py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)    at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by:
>   java.sql.SQLException: DAY_OF_MONTH   at
>   com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:129)
>     at
>   com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97)
>     at
>   com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:89)
>     at
>   com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:63)
>     at
>   com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:73)
>     at
>   com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:85)
>     at
>   com.mysql.cj.jdbc.result.ResultSetImpl.getDate(ResultSetImpl.java:755)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$jdbc$JdbcUtils$$makeGetter$2.apply(JdbcUtils.scala:389)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$jdbc$JdbcUtils$$makeGetter$2.apply(JdbcUtils.scala:387)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$$anon$1.getNext(JdbcUtils.scala:356)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$$anon$1.getNext(JdbcUtils.scala:338)
>     at org.apache.spark.util.NextIterator.hasNext(NextIterator.scala:73)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.util.CompletionIterator.hasNext(CompletionIterator.scala:31)
>     at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.UnsafeExternalRowSorter.sort(UnsafeExternalRowSorter.java:216)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.exchange.ShuffleExchangeExec$$anonfun$2.apply(ShuffleExchangeExec.scala:295)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.exchange.ShuffleExchangeExec$$anonfun$2.apply(ShuffleExchangeExec.scala:266)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$24.apply(RDD.scala:836)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$24.apply(RDD.scala:836)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
>     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
>     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
>     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
>     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:99)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:55)
>     at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:121)  at
>   org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:408)
>     at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:414)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>     ... 1 more Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.WrongArgumentException:
>   DAY_OF_MONTH  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>     at
>   com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:61)
>     at
>   com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:105)
>     at
>   com.mysql.cj.result.SqlDateValueFactory.localCreateFromDate(SqlDateValueFactory.java:85)
>     at
>   com.mysql.cj.result.SqlDateValueFactory.localCreateFromDate(SqlDateValueFactory.java:50)
>     at
>   com.mysql.cj.result.AbstractDateTimeValueFactory.createFromDate(AbstractDateTimeValueFactory.java:67)
>     at
>   com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.MysqlBinaryValueDecoder.decodeDate(MysqlBinaryValueDecoder.java:129)
>     at
>   com.mysql.cj.protocol.result.AbstractResultsetRow.decodeAndCreateReturnValue(AbstractResultsetRow.java:90)
>     at
>   com.mysql.cj.protocol.result.AbstractResultsetRow.getValueFromBytes(AbstractResultsetRow.java:241)
>     at
>   com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.result.ByteArrayRow.getValue(ByteArrayRow.java:91)
>     ... 29 more Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   DAY_OF_MONTH  at
>   java.util.GregorianCalendar.computeTime(GregorianCalendar.java:2648)
>     at java.util.Calendar.updateTime(Calendar.java:3393)    at
>   java.util.Calendar.getTimeInMillis(Calendar.java:1782)    at
>   com.mysql.cj.result.SqlDateValueFactory.localCreateFromDate(SqlDateValueFactory.java:82)
>     ... 35 more
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/mnt/yarn/usercache/livy/appcache/application_1583217406561_0001/container_1583217406561_0001_01_000001/PyGlue.zip/awsglue/dynamicframe.py",
>   line 294, in count
>       return self._jdf.count()   File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/livy/appcache/application_1583217406561_0001/container_1583217406561_0001_01_000001/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py",
>   line 1257, in **call**
>       answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)   File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/livy/appcache/application_1583217406561_0001/container_1583217406561_0001_01_000001/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py",
>   line 63, in deco
>       return f(*a, **kw)   File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/livy/appcache/application_1583217406561_0001/container_1583217406561_0001_01_000001/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py",
>   line 328, in get_return_value
>       format(target_id, ".", name), value) py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o1031.count. :
>   org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure:
>   Task 0 in stage 194.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task
>   0.3 in stage 194.0 (, executor 28): java.sql.SQLException: DAY_OF_MONTH   at
>   com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:129)
>     at
>   com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97)
>     at
>   com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:89)
>     at
>   com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:63)
>     at
>   com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:73)
>     at
>   com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:85)
>     at
>   com.mysql.cj.jdbc.result.ResultSetImpl.getDate(ResultSetImpl.java:755)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$jdbc$JdbcUtils$$makeGetter$2.apply(JdbcUtils.scala:389)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$jdbc$JdbcUtils$$makeGetter$2.apply(JdbcUtils.scala:387)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$$anon$1.getNext(JdbcUtils.scala:356)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$$anon$1.getNext(JdbcUtils.scala:338)
>     at org.apache.spark.util.NextIterator.hasNext(NextIterator.scala:73)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.util.CompletionIterator.hasNext(CompletionIterator.scala:31)
>     at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.UnsafeExternalRowSorter.sort(UnsafeExternalRowSorter.java:216)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.exchange.ShuffleExchangeExec$$anonfun$2.apply(ShuffleExchangeExec.scala:295)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.exchange.ShuffleExchangeExec$$anonfun$2.apply(ShuffleExchangeExec.scala:266)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$24.apply(RDD.scala:836)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$24.apply(RDD.scala:836)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
>     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
>     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
>     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
>     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:99)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:55)
>     at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:121)  at
>   org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:408)
>     at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:414)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by:
>   com.mysql.cj.exceptions.WrongArgumentException: DAY_OF_MONTH  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>     at
>   com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:61)
>     at
>   com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:105)
>     at
>   com.mysql.cj.result.SqlDateValueFactory.localCreateFromDate(SqlDateValueFactory.java:85)
>     at
>   com.mysql.cj.result.SqlDateValueFactory.localCreateFromDate(SqlDateValueFactory.java:50)
>     at
>   com.mysql.cj.result.AbstractDateTimeValueFactory.createFromDate(AbstractDateTimeValueFactory.java:67)
>     at
>   com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.MysqlBinaryValueDecoder.decodeDate(MysqlBinaryValueDecoder.java:129)
>     at
>   com.mysql.cj.protocol.result.AbstractResultsetRow.decodeAndCreateReturnValue(AbstractResultsetRow.java:90)
>     at
>   com.mysql.cj.protocol.result.AbstractResultsetRow.getValueFromBytes(AbstractResultsetRow.java:241)
>     at
>   com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.result.ByteArrayRow.getValue(ByteArrayRow.java:91)
>     ... 29 more Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   DAY_OF_MONTH  at
>   java.util.GregorianCalendar.computeTime(GregorianCalendar.java:2648)
>     at java.util.Calendar.updateTime(Calendar.java:3393)    at
>   java.util.Calendar.getTimeInMillis(Calendar.java:1782)    at
>   com.mysql.cj.result.SqlDateValueFactory.localCreateFromDate(SqlDateValueFactory.java:82)
>     ... 35 more
>
> Driver stacktrace:    at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1889)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1877)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1876)
>     at
>   scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
>     at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1876)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:926)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:926)
>     at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)   at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:926)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2110)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2059)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2048)
>     at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:737)
>     at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2061)    at
>   org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2082)     at
>   org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2101)     at
>   org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2126)     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.count(RDD.scala:1168)    at
>   com.amazonaws.services.glue.DynamicFrame.count(DynamicFrame.scala:1145)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)  at
>   py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)    at
>   py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)     at
>   py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
>     at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)   at
>   py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)    at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by:
>   java.sql.SQLException: DAY_OF_MONTH   at
>   com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:129)
>     at
>   com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97)
>     at
>   com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:89)
>     at
>   com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:63)
>     at
>   com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:73)
>     at
>   com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:85)
>     at
>   com.mysql.cj.jdbc.result.ResultSetImpl.getDate(ResultSetImpl.java:755)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$jdbc$JdbcUtils$$makeGetter$2.apply(JdbcUtils.scala:389)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$jdbc$JdbcUtils$$makeGetter$2.apply(JdbcUtils.scala:387)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$$anon$1.getNext(JdbcUtils.scala:356)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$$anon$1.getNext(JdbcUtils.scala:338)
>     at org.apache.spark.util.NextIterator.hasNext(NextIterator.scala:73)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.util.CompletionIterator.hasNext(CompletionIterator.scala:31)
>     at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.UnsafeExternalRowSorter.sort(UnsafeExternalRowSorter.java:216)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.exchange.ShuffleExchangeExec$$anonfun$2.apply(ShuffleExchangeExec.scala:295)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.exchange.ShuffleExchangeExec$$anonfun$2.apply(ShuffleExchangeExec.scala:266)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$24.apply(RDD.scala:836)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$24.apply(RDD.scala:836)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
>     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
>     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
>     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
>     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:99)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:55)
>     at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:121)  at
>   org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:408)
>     at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:414)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>     ... 1 more Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.WrongArgumentException:
>   DAY_OF_MONTH  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>     at
>   com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:61)
>     at
>   com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:105)
>     at
>   com.mysql.cj.result.SqlDateValueFactory.localCreateFromDate(SqlDateValueFactory.java:85)
>     at
>   com.mysql.cj.result.SqlDateValueFactory.localCreateFromDate(SqlDateValueFactory.java:50)
>     at
>   com.mysql.cj.result.AbstractDateTimeValueFactory.createFromDate(AbstractDateTimeValueFactory.java:67)
>     at
>   com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.MysqlBinaryValueDecoder.decodeDate(MysqlBinaryValueDecoder.java:129)
>     at
>   com.mysql.cj.protocol.result.AbstractResultsetRow.decodeAndCreateReturnValue(AbstractResultsetRow.java:90)
>     at
>   com.mysql.cj.protocol.result.AbstractResultsetRow.getValueFromBytes(AbstractResultsetRow.java:241)
>     at
>   com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.result.ByteArrayRow.getValue(ByteArrayRow.java:91)
>     ... 29 more Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   DAY_OF_MONTH  at
>   java.util.GregorianCalendar.computeTime(GregorianCalendar.java:2648)
>     at java.util.Calendar.updateTime(Calendar.java:3393)    at
>   java.util.Calendar.getTimeInMillis(Calendar.java:1782)    at
>   com.mysql.cj.result.SqlDateValueFactory.localCreateFromDate(SqlDateValueFactory.java:82)
>     ... 35 more

Comment: I get the error when I use any actions like count() or show().

Comment: If I read the same file as spark DataFrame and perform some action, then I get no error.

Comment: Can you please provide some code snippet, table schema, etc.

Comment: create dynamic frame code is as shown above (I have removed the actual table names and endpoint), I then convert this to DataFrame usning toDF(). After this when I do printSchema() then it shows the schema(which I cannot share here), but if I use any spark action like count() or show() then I get the above error.

Answer (score -1):

I got this kinda of error recently.

Whenever I read a table, my spark script was throwing:

```
java.sql.SQLException: DAY_OF_MONTH
```

After, some investigation I discovered the problem was an invalid value on a date column, in my case it was something like `2020-10-00`.

## Solutions

- Find rows with invalid dates and fix them

or

- Read the date column as string using a [customSchema](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-jdbc.html) and handle it afterwards

## How to find invalid dates

### 1. Query the DB for invalid dates

You can probably build a query to find invalid dates using [ISDATE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isdate-transact-sql).

### 2. Query with your spark script

You can also find this with your spark script (I had to as I had only select privileges in the DB and could not run routines).

To query the DB for invalid dates within your script, I suggest you to retrieve the date column as string first.

```
df =
...
  "dbtable": "(select id, CAST(your_date_col AS CHAR) from your_table) as r"
...
```

And afterwards find the invalid dates:

```
df.filter(col("your_date_col") != '0000-00-00') \
  .withColumn("dt", to_date(col("your_date_col"),"yyyy-MM-dd")) \
  .filter(col("dt").isNull()) \
  .show()
```

You'll get something like:

```
+------+-------------+----+
|    id|your_date_col|  dt|
+------+-------------+----+
|333300|   2020-10-00|null|
+------+-------------+----+
```

---

Hope it helps, cheers.

Comment: Also, be mindful of [zeroDateTimeBehavior](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html). In my case I set it to `convertToNull`.

Comment: This is MySQL not MSSQL